# MVC3 model DisplayFormat and JSON

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model which has some double properties on it, and with them come a DisplayFormat which converts the double into a nice readable percent.. example

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
public Nullable<double> Yearly_act_pct { get; set; }
```

This works fine in HTML partials where I wrap the call in

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Yearly_act_pct)
```

However, when I dump some of these objects into a JSON feed, the DisplayFormats seem to be ignored, so I end up with raw decimals, and often big ones.

How can I make this

```
return Json(myObjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

respect the DisplayFormats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `return Json(myObjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` actually returns a `JsonResult`. The internals of the `JsonResult` perform a call:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
```

If you look at MSDN for [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) you will there is a simple conversion. This implementation does not appear to honor DisplayFormat.

You can write a class derived from `JsonResult` that honors the DisplayFormat attribute.

Comment: Programmatically, how do I read an object for the DisplayFormat settings of its properties?

Answer (score 1):

The `DataAnnotations` namespace attributes will only handle it for dynamic data controls and display formatting.  What you'd need to do is just some basic rounding before passing your object to the `Json()` method.  Something like this would suffice:

```
myObjects.Yearly_act_pct = Math.Round(myObjects.Yearly_act_pct, 2); // provided you wanted to round to nearest two fractional digits
return Json(myObjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will give you the "small double" value, but you're still passing a `double`, not a `string` that can be a formatted `double`.  Not sure if that makes sense, but a `double` is a `double`, and the best you can do is to round it so it doesn't have an excess amount of fractional digits.

Answer (score 1):

One of the work arounds that people have been using when needing to customize the output format when working with Serialization is to create a string property:

```
    [DataMember(Name = "price", Order = 23)]
    [XmlElement("price", Order = 23)]
    public string Price_String
    {
        get
        {
            return Formatter.FormatAsCurrency(this.Price);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Price = Formatter.ParseCurrency(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Formatter is a custom class I have that handels parsing/formatting for specific types. These are not relevant but I'll include them:

```
    public static string FormatAsCurrency(decimal? amount)
    {
        return amount.HasValue ? String.Format("{0:C}USD", amount).Replace("$","") : null;
    }
    public static decimal ParseCurrency(string value)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? decimal.Parse(value.Replace("USD", "")) : 0;
    }
    public static decimal? ParseNullableCurrency(string value)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? decimal.Parse(value.Replace("USD", "")) as decimal? : null;
    }
```

In my example I've marked up my properties for both DataContract and Xml serialization. This is not ideal but at the time was the only work around.

I also created a method in my controller to return a response "

```
    public ContentResult GetContentResult(object responseObject)
    {
        #region Output Format
        if (this.ResponseFormat == ResponseFormatEnum.JSON)
        {
            string json = "";

            try
            {
                System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer jsonserializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(responseObject.GetType());
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                jsonserializer.WriteObject(ms, responseObject);
                json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                ms.Close();
                ms.Dispose();
                jsonserializer = null;
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }

            return new ContentResult() { Content = json, ContentType = "application/json" };

        }
        else
        {
            string xml = "";
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(responseObject.GetType());
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                serializer.Serialize(ms, responseObject, ns);
                xml = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray()); ms.Close();
                ms.Dispose();
                serializer = null;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return new ContentResult() { Content = xml, ContentType = "text/xml" };
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And to use it:

```
    public ActionResult Feed()
    {
        ViewModels.API.Deals.Response response = new ViewModels.API.Deals.Get();
        return GetContentResult(response);            
    }
```

My example is a bit more complicated than what you are using but it works (both for XML and JSON)